# How to read/write file?

Tags: haskell

I am writing a test and my test's scenario is:

- append line to file
- assert
- append again
- assert again

And I don't know how to implement this simple scenario in Haskell: I always get `openFile: resource busy (file is locked)`! I read [THIS](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/System-IO.html#g:8) and I cannot understand what the problem is. I open the file in `ReadMode` in my "assert" block and in non-buffering mode! And I append a new line to this file (with `appendFile`). Why is it unsafe and should be locked?! It's safe operation in all languages, so, I suppose it must exist some way to workaround this strange Haskell limitation, is there any?

I tried to write my own `appendFile` which calls `hFlush` + `hClose` at the end. I suppose `hClose` really closes a file and releases a lock. The same result. My code (asserts) work fine when I append to file from another application (notepad and similar), it does not look as "lazy-problem", it looks as a redundant lock.

Currently, I see only one: to call `echo "..." >> myfile` in my unit-test, is there any way to append a line to a file while it's opened in the same Haskell application for reading without to call shell's "echo"?

EDIT:

The test scenario is like this:

```hs
  , testCase "common scenario" $ do
    withSystemTempDirectory "something" $ \tmpDir -> do
      let dir = P.absDir tmpDir
          f = dir </> P.relFile "my.log"
          f1 = P.toString f
      appendFile f1 "aaa\n"
      appendFile f1 "bbb\n"
      appendFile f1 "\n\n\n"
      appendFile f1 "ccc\n"
      appendFile f1 "ddd"

      fm <- myReader f

      ln <- myRead fm
      assertEqual "unexpected line" (Added "aaa") ln

      -- I want to add here appendFile or something similar and useful

      ln <- myRead fm
      assertEqual "unexpected line" (Added "aaa") ln
```

Comment: Can you post code that illustrates the problem?

Comment: You can't get a handle on read and a handle on write at same time. You can get multiple handles on read or a single handle on write.

Comment: @freestyle exactly! And I thought the same. So I have a handle for read (opened as `openFile (P.toString _path) ReadMode` - inside `myReader`) and another one inside `appendFile` (it opens the file for append, appends and immediately closes it with `hClose`)

Comment: @RandomB I don't know exactly why haskell developers did by this way, maybe this constraint leads to more portable code or less logical mistakes or finding errors in lazy IO.

Comment: maybe you are right :) Well, so the best solution will be "echo" I think ;)

Comment: @RandomB About echo, I don't know depends on what you are test exactly what logic you try to test?

Comment: External application writing into a file in parallel to me, "echo" will be close to the real use case TBH

Comment: Interesting, how `myRead` works? How it waits a new message?

Comment: it has little bit complex logic but in general it analyzes the size of file, and optionally mtime, I avoided to use file system events because I needed cross-plaftorm and simple solution. So it's just polling with some period, not "waiting".

Comment: You can store the file path and offset instead of storing the file handle. When reading, open the file and make an offset, and then save the new offset. However, this will not work if the file can be moved, but under Windows your option will also not work in this case, as the system does not allow it to be done if the file is open by some process (if I remember correctly).

Comment: yes, on Windows, you cannot remove/move opened file. Your hint is good, I implemented optionally such behavior too, thank you for it :)

Comment: Can you just use the same handle for all operations on the file?

Comment: Unfortunately, no in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Haskell98 standard [requires](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/io.html#sect21.2.3) that implementations enforce an aggressive file locking scheme, and GHC follows this part of the standard.  (For GHC, this locking scheme is internal to the runtime of the Haskell program and independent of any O/S file locking support.)

The rationale for this section of the standard has to do with lazy I/O and the potential for unsafe or unpredictable behavior in common scenarios, such as reading a file, processing it, and writing out a new version:

```
main = do
    txt <- readFile "foo.txt"
    let txt' = map toLower txt
    writeFile "foo.txt" txt'
```

If this program worked in Haskell, it would always truncate "foo.txt" to zero length, and when the programmer tried to figure out why by printing out the intermediate output:

```
main = do
    txt <- readFile "foo.txt"
    let txt' = map toLower txt
    putStrLn txt'
    writeFile "foo.txt" txt'
```

it would magically start working as intended.

There are many ways to "fix" this, and the one the Haskell98 standards committee settled on, probably after considering this example and dozens of more complicated examples, was that the implementation should err on the side of disallowing a file to be simultaneously opened for both reading and writing under two different handles, even if no lazy I/O operations were actually used.

If we could travel back in time and get you on the Haskell98 committee, we might be able to fix this, but as things stand, we'll just have to accept it.

Fortunately, GHC exposes the locking internals, so you can release the internal lock via the `release` function from `GHC.IO.FD`.  In particular, the following example fails with a lock error but can be made to work by uncommenting the `release` line:

```
import GHC.IO.FD (release)
import GHC.IO.Handle.FD (handleToFd)
import System.IO

main = do
  let f = "foo.txt"

  writeFile f "hello\n"

  h <- openFile f ReadMode

  -- uncomment the next line to make this work    
  -- release =<< handleToFd h
  appendFile f "world\n"
```

To be clear, the issue you are encountering in your test is that `myReader` opens the file in `ReadMode` and keeps it open, and any following `appendFile` will fail when it attempts to call `openFile` on the same file in `AppendMode` (which is treated as a "writer" for the purposes of locking).  Reimplementing `appendFile` does not help, because the problem is that `appendFile` is failing to *open* the file, not failing to flush it or *close* it.

It should be sufficient, in your test, to release the lock right after calling `myReader`, and the interleaved reads on the (now unlocked) handle and `appendFile` calls (which lock and unlock the file before returning) should work fine.

Comment: Huh. There's a `release`, but no `acquire`? I mean, I guess it seems like it would be unusual to want to re-enter the world of lazy IO once you promised you weren't in it maybe?

Comment: BTW, tested - it works. Thanks a lot!